# Enterprise Architect Patterns with MDG Technology

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I created my own Toolbox using MDG technology- Enterprise architect, and I integrated patterns which I created previously with my own toolbox. I stored the patterns in "Resources-->Basic patterns" as is shown in the following figure, till now everything is fine. 
[image]

After I published my MDG technology and try to test my work, I found the following error. 
 [image]

I want to know how to solve this problem. Are there any different methods to keep my patterns well integrated with my customized toolbox.

Comment: Did you add your pattern to your MDG technology? See http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/modeling_tools/addingpatterninmdgtechnolo.html

Comment: thanks,  that the same way which I add patterns into my MDG technology, but when I try testing the pattern. I found the error which is displayed above. What the problem? and should I create a profile of the pattern?